# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Datatable

Tags: c#

Lo que quiero es llenar un `DataTable` con direcciones de mis imágenes, y esta tabla se incrementara según el número de archivos de una carpeta en la cual almaceno mis imágenes, solo que me sale un error que no he podido resolver y aquí está mi código.

Código de Tabla:

```
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Columns.Add("Ruta");
DataRow dr = dTable.NewRow();
dr["Ruta"] = "Imagen";
dTable.Rows.Add(dr);
dataInfo.DataSource = dTable;
```

Por el momento me debería solo de mostrar una tabla con la columna ruta y con el valor imagen, pero me marca el error del título.

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.

El error me lo marca en la siguiente línea:

```
dataInfo.DataSource = dTable;
```

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `dataInfo`?

Comment: @Flxtr es un datagridview

Comment: Cómo estás creando dataInfo?

Comment: Hagamos una prueba, agrega esta línea antes de donde te marca el error  `dataInfo = new DataGridView();`

Comment: @Flxtr ya me deja pasar a ver el formulario, solo que no me muestra ninguna columna, todo esta en gris, mi datagridview no lo declare en mi codigo lo agregue desde el cuadro de herramientas

Comment: Me parece bastante extraño, no veo que tenga algún tema tu código. Otra cosa que podemos hacer es llenar los datos a través de un `BindingSource`, [en esta liga](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx) está la documentación oficial y un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Tu control no esta siendo instanciado en el método Initialize de la forma.

En pocas palabras Visual Studio no esta haciendo su trabajo.

Lo más sencillo es borrar el DataGridView del formulario y crearlo nuevamente para que Visual Studio ponga el codigo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

si dataInfo es un DataSet
debes de :

```
dataInfo[0]
```

referenciar la tabla a donde la asignaste 
por que un dataset puede guardar varias tablas